# iOS 10 Messages Extension - Wrong Layout when using Storyboard Segue

Tags: autolayout, ios10, uistoryboardsegue, imessage, ios-messages-extension

When using Segues in Messages Extension Application the layout gets messed up. 
**Is there any way to solve this issue while still using storrybord segues?**

**Screenshots:** 
*(Note: The first and second View / ViewController are identical. The segue-type doesn't matter)*


**Expanded Presentation Style:**

[image: 1Exp]
[image: 2Exp]

**Compact Presentation Style:**

[image: 1Comp]
[image: 2Comp]

**Update 1:**

The top and bottom layout guides reset after a segue

- compact:

  - top: should be: **0** but is: **20**
  - bottom: should be: **44** but is: **0**
- expanded:

  - top: should be: **86** but is: **20**
  - bottom: should be: **44** but is: **0**

***P.S. Can someone create a new "messages-extension" tag?***

Comment: As message app are in beta test, I think you should open a new thread on the Apple dev forum : https://forums.developer.apple.com/community/app-frameworks/imessage-apps-and-stickers
Also you can open a bug report ;)

Comment: @RomOne Seems like someone already did [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/52606)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this won't always be necessary, but I ended up using a combination of a constraint outlet, presentationStyle variable, and viewDidLayoutSubviews() to overcome this bug/oversight.

In my DetailViewController:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myViewTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
var presentationStyle: MSMessagesAppPresentationStyle?

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    if presentationStyle == .expanded {
        myViewTopConstraint.constant = 86
    } else {
        myViewTopConstraint.constant = 0
    }
}
```

And in my MainViewController:

```
override func willTransition(to presentationStyle: MSMessagesAppPresentationStyle) {
    if let detailController = presentedViewController as? DetailViewController {
        detailController.presentationStyle = presentationStyle
    }
}
```

And in case it makes a difference, my segue presents modally as a Page Sheet.

Answer (score 0):

in my app, viewcontroller in .expand mode set :

```
view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

in .compact mode set it to false

```
view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = false
```

it should work.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution I arrived at with the help of http://sandmoose.com/post/35714028270/storyboards-with-custom-container-view-controllers

In your entry point view controller, place a container view that has auto layout constraints aligning the top and bottom of the container view to the top and bottom layout guides.

The container view itself then needs to embed any view controller that you segue to. This way destination view controllers will always live in the confines of the container view. The container view will also be constrained correctly by the top and bottom layout guides of the initial view controller.

One way to achieve this:
Implement a protocol that will receive notifications for segues - something like:

```
protocol SegueDelegate {
  func willSegue(to: UIViewController)

  func didSegue(to: UIViewController)
}
```

Implement a subclass of UIViewController that has a reference to SegueDelegate e.g.

```
class ContainedViewController: UIViewController {
  weak var segueDelegate: SegueDelegate?

  ...

  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    segueDelegate?.willSegue(to: segue.destination)
  }
}
```

Have your initial messages view controller implement the protocol.

```
extension MSMessagesAppViewController: SegueDelegate {

  func didSegue(to destination: UIViewController) {
    guard let destination = destination as? ContainedViewController else {
      return
    }
    // Reference through IBOutlet or something
    containerViewController.embed(destination)
  }
}
```

The containerViewController here must implement an embed method that swaps the displaying view controller with the new one e.g.

```
class ContainerViewController: UIViewController {
  ...

  func embed(_ viewController: UIViewController) {
    let source = childViewControllers.first
    if source == viewController {
        return
    }

    source?.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
    addChildViewController(viewController)
    if let source = source {
        // Do transition here if you want
        viewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height)
        view.addSubview(viewController.view)
        viewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

        source.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
        source.removeFromParentViewController()
    } else {
        viewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height)
        view.addSubview(viewController.view)
        viewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }

    // Assigned in viewDidLoad of MSMessagesAppViewController or similar
    segueDelegate?.didSegue(to: viewController)
  }

}
```